# Setting latest revision has been delayed

Tags: 8, nodes, caching

We are (still) using Drupal 8, the latest version, as a CMS for content editing.
Our platform is huge and it has 100+ editors who are constantly adding/editing content, and also 20 importers which are importing content all the time.

We are hosting our platform on Azure Kubernetes Service, and using custom Azure VM where we host our custom MySQL server. We have had this setup for a year and a half.

Everything worked well until 3 weeks ago when we started to experience a really strange issue: Setting the latest revision has been delayed

This is exactly what is happening:

- Editor adds the node, everything is saved properly
- Editor opens that node to edit, he/she saves it but the old content
  has been displayed
- When we check the revision page, the default/current revision is not the latest one, it's the one before
- After a maximum of 10 minutes, the latest revision has been automatically saved as
  the default/current one and the content is displayed properly

For the caching layer, we are using Memcached and Akamai, but Akamai is disabled for logged-in users.

(We are currently in a process of upgrading to Drupal 9, but this issue came across so we are trying to put effort there to fix it)

Did anyone have any similar/same experience with revisions lately?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I haven't had this exact problem, but if it were me, memcached seems like the likely culprit. Maybe try disabling memcached to test if the problem persists or not, as a test.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan for your answer. We were thinking about disabling Memcached, but as our website is really high throughput application, we are hesitating to enable DB cache, because it can lead to outage. The problem is that this issue is happening only in the Production environment, so we can't replicate on local, dev, and stage. Now we are trying to put more logging to find out what is happening and also to try with Redis cache.